# Windows does not maximze to full screen

Tags: windows-8.1

When i maximize a window, the window will only fill up about 80% of the screen. The remaining 20% is on the right side of the screen, where the desktop is visible.

I am able to restore the window, and put it on top of this space, but when i maximize the window, i only get the 80%.

The start button and task bar is in its "normal" position.

How can i disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following link , this may help :- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/window-is-maximized-but-not-to-full-screen-size/01a8300c-01b3-4fb2-bbeb-f396ef81c4b3

Let me know if this works.

The answers specified  the the above link :-

**Answer 1** :- 
start closing programs that had notification area icons .

**Answer 2** :- application called **Pidgin** has been identified as the cause in the forum . Closing the application has solved problems for the user.

**Alternatively Answer 3** :-

- Please place your computer in a Clean Boot Scenerio to ensure that there is not any 3rd party services conflicting with Windows functioning normally. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331796

**Step 1:** Start the System Configuration Utility
Click **Start**, type **msconfig** in the **Start Search** box, and then press **ENTER**.
If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or provide confirmation.

**Step 2**: Configure Selective Startup options

- In the **System Configuration Utility** dialog box, click **Selective Startup** on the **General tab**.
- Click to clear the **Load Startup** Items check box. **Note** The **Use Original Boot.ini** check box is unavailable.
- Click the **Services tab**.
- Click to select the **Hide All Microsoft Services** check box.
- Click **Disable All**, and then click **OK**.
- When you are prompted, click **Restart**.
- Create an Alternate Local Administrator account and verify if you are still experiencing this issue.
- Boot into Safe Mode and attempt to maximize your screen and verify if you are still experiencing this issue.

Comment: Can you post the text from that link and edit your answer, just in case the site becomes unavailable at some time in the future? If you do, I'll thumb it up. Otherwise I won't.

Comment: Hi  LPChip , Added the answer from the link :)

Comment: It was a program in the notification area (Gadwin printscreen) which was "occupying" the space, even thou it did not have any visible windows.